# ¿Como mostrar solamente las imágenes de openstreetmap en React-native-maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, react-native, map

En `react-native-maps` hay un componente que se llama `UrlTile` lo cual dibuja una capa sobre el mapa, es ahí donde integramos las imágenes o capa de openstreet-map.

¿habrá una forma de solo renderizar el `UrlTile` y no consumir los servicios de Google Maps?

Ya he intentado con `react-native-webview-leaflet` pero he leído y hay sus desventajas en usar esta librería, me gustaría usar `react-native-maps` como primera opción.

Dejaré el código que llevo hasta ahora.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapView, { Marker, UrlTile } from 'react-native-maps'


class Ejemplo extended Component {

  render () {
      <MapView>
          <UrlTile urlTemplate="http://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"  zIndex={900} />
      </MapView>

    }
}
```